# gdm session without setting default

Tags: 14.04, gnome, xorg, login, gdm

I have a locally created session to let users login to a special session at times (i've called it /usr/share/xsessions/remote.desktop). The problem is that they normally login to gnome (/usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop) and get annoyed after logging in to the remote session and finding that is the default choice next time they login.

I would like my session to work a little like the failsafe gnome-session by not being the default session next time the user log in. Is it possible to configure a session to not set default session?